# Is Google Dogfooding Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, frameworks, angularjs

I've recently started learning Angular.js, and so far I'm extremely impressed by the framework.

I was wondering though (since it's being developed at Google) if there are any examples of **Google using Angular.js "out in the wild"**?

I tried searching the source of a number of Google pages for variations of `"ngApp"`, or angular.js script includes, but found nothing.

Evidence that Google is dogfooding Angular.js in their own public web development would be a HUGE value-add to the framework for me.

Comment: Have a look https://www.googlesciencefair.com/

Comment: This questions seem very real and interesting.

Comment: The Google Developer Console (if you use their cloud products) uses Angular extensively.

Comment: Check https://www.madewithangular.com/categories/google

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, Google has build large applications with AngularJS: http://blog.angularjs.org/2012/06/doubleclick-super-powered-by-angularjs.html

See also the meetup talk about it: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oJoAnVRIVQo

Comment: Exactly the kind of thing I was look for! Thanks.

Comment: I like the user was weary of using Angular, since google has a funny way of closing projects.  Anyway, glad to know I can use it in good faith.

Comment: Also see: [builtwith.angularjs.org](https://builtwith.angularjs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.artcopycode.com/ was done in Angular, although it's not much of an application.

Comment: Took a look at the site and it's using BackBone with Marionette, not Angular...

Comment: @GabrielYarra A lot can change in a year and a half.

Comment: I find that hilariously ironic @GabrielYarra